# Possible to query a database with subclass entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

Ok, lets say I have a model.

```
  @Entity
  public class Person extends Model {
        public String name;
        public String email;
    }
```

Now.  I have a couple of transient fields that don't exist in the database, but I need to access them.  Basically they are fields for displaying the Person on a web page.

```
@Entity
        public class PersonDisplay extends Person {

        @Transient
        public String DT_RowClass = ""; 
        @Transient
        public String cellColor = "";
    }
```

Is it possible to query the PersonDisplay and get the Person object plus the PersonDisplay default values?

Like this.

```
PersonDisplay display = PersonDisplay.find("byEmail" , "test@test.com").first();
```

I'm running into a few errors when I do this.

Let me know if I need to explain this again.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the [`@PostLoad`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html) annotation, which you can use to initialize any transient variables.